# jQuery scrolling from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a graphic that has many clickable areas and displays data below depending on where you clicked.  Now the client wishes to have it also scroll to the data below if they click so I need to adjust my script to include this functionality but not sure how to go about it:

THE TOP WITH GRAPHIC:

```
<div id="bam-container">
    <div class="gear-right-1" data-class="gear-right-1" data-alt-class="gear-right-1-alt" data-hover="true" data-info-prefix="bam-info-small-1"></div>
    <div class="gear-right-2" data-class="gear-right-2" data-alt-class="gear-right-2-alt" data-hover="true" data-info-prefix="bam-info-small-2"></div>
    <div class="gear-right-3-alt selected" data-class="gear-right-3" data-alt-class="gear-right-3-alt" data-hover="true" data-info-prefix="bam-info-small-3"></div>
    <div class="gear-right-4" data-class="gear-right-4" data-alt-class="gear-right-4-alt" data-hover="true" data-info-prefix="bam-info-small-4"></div>
    <div class="gear-right-5" data-class="gear-right-5" data-alt-class="gear-right-5-alt" data-hover="true" data-info-prefix="bam-info-small-5"></div>
    <div class="gear-right-6-alt"></div>

    <div class="gear-left-alt"></div>
    <div class="gear-left-text-1" data-class="gear-left-text-1" data-alt-class="gear-left-text-1-alt" data-hover="true" data-info-prefix="bam-info-small-7"></div>
    <div class="gear-left-text-2" data-class="gear-left-text-2" data-alt-class="gear-left-text-2-alt" data-hover="true" data-info-prefix="bam-info-small-8"></div>
    <div class="gear-left-text-3" data-class="gear-left-text-3" data-alt-class="gear-left-text-3-alt" data-hover="true" data-info-prefix="bam-info-small-9"></div>
</div>
```

THE BOTTOM WITH DATA:

```
<div id="bam-items-container">
    <div id="bam-info-small-1-1" class="bam-title" style="display: none;">Discovery</div>
<div id="bam-info-small-1-1" class="bam-info bam-insight" style="display: none;">
<div class="header">Insights</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis laoreet elit, ut tempus nulla. Suspendisse elit ligula, tempor in rhoncus id, consectetur id dui. Proin sed nibh quis urna hendrerit ornare sed et ligula.</p>
```

The Current JS:

```
<script>

var globalInfoPrefix = "bam-info";

$(function() {

    var hoverItems = $("[data-hover='true']");

    $("[id^='" + globalInfoPrefix + "']").hide();

    hoverItems.hover(
        //handlerIn
        function () {
            var gear = $(this);
            if(!gear.hasClass("selected")) {
                var inactiveClass = gear.attr("data-class");
                var activeClass = gear.attr("data-alt-class");

                gear.addClass(activeClass);
                gear.removeClass(inactiveClass);
            }
        },
        //handlerOut
        function () {
            var gear = $(this);

            if (!gear.hasClass("selected")) {
                var inactiveClass = gear.attr("data-class");
                var activeClass = gear.attr("data-alt-class");

                gear.addClass(inactiveClass);
                gear.removeClass(activeClass);
            }
        }
    );

    hoverItems.click(function () {
        var gear = $(this);
        var inactiveClass = gear.attr("data-class");
        var activeClass = gear.attr("data-alt-class");
        var prefix = gear.attr("data-info-prefix");



        hoverItems.each(function () {
            var smallGear = $(this);
            smallGear.removeClass("selected");
            smallGear.removeClass(smallGear.attr("data-alt-class"));
            smallGear.addClass(smallGear.attr("data-class"));
        });

        gear.addClass(activeClass);
        gear.addClass("selected");
        gear.removeClass(inactiveClass);

        $("[id^='" + globalInfoPrefix + "']").hide();
        $("[id^='" + prefix + "']").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: do you simply want to scroll down to a div?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery scroll To Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: Yes to Adween.  Thanks Patrick, I tried looking at that but mostly it was referring to focussable elements rather than a div.

Comment: @Chad The process is the same, as it uses the elements id and its position and then sets scrollTop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user clicks something on the graphic you need to get the position of your content div and then animate the body scrollTop to that position.

I created an example fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/taneleero/3EngC/

Basically you just need to add this code in your hoverItems.click event function:

```
$("html, body").animate({
  scrollTop: $('#bam-items-container').offset().top
});
```

Hope I understood your problem right.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this.